# Regex- How to exclude words

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to match and exclude specific words using regex. I'm essentially trying to match all strings in a 24 hour with an option of an am or pm. However I would like to excludes string that begin with 2014 or 2013. For example:

Input:

```
11 45 pm
12 34 am
1230pm
2013pm
12 pm 
12p
2014 pm
```

Desired output:

```
11 45 pm
12 34 am
1230pm
12 pm
```

I would like to only use one regex to match this. I know how to accomplish this task with two regex's.

I'm using the following command:

```
grep -E '^(?!2014)(?!2013)([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])( )?[0-5][0-9]?\s?(am|pm)?' output.txt
```

with no success. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: I'm using grep to do this

Comment: If it has a pm or am in it it's NOT 24h format to begin with ...

Comment: If you know how you want it to be with two regexs, why not do that? What is the urge people to have to have a regex limited to one regex....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern like:

```
^((?:0?[0-9]|1[012])\s?(?:[0-5][0-9])?\s?[ap]m)
```

Here, I've assumed that either `am` or `pm` is present at the end of statement.

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

`[0-9]{1,2}\s*[0-9]{1,2}(?<!2013)(?<!2014)\s*(am|pm)`